Hi, Can anyone help me to solve the error regarding "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException"
My code is
@RequestMapping(value ="login",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String welcomepage(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String password ,ModelMap model){
    model.put("password", password);
    model.put("name", name);
    return "welcomepage";
}

Got below error
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'password' for method parameter type string is not present. Could not resolve parameter [1] in public getting this in console.
tried with
public String welcomepage(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam int id ,ModelMap model) have changed id parameter out of the method but not working.

Show the request that triggered that error.  For request parameters you have to send the parameters on the URL, are you?  It would look like /login?name=bob&password=tom
